Power Automate flow for Sharepoint List to Azure Devops work item integration Bad Request - Invalid URL Issue
I have created a Power Automate flow to capture changes on a SharePoint List:

Here's the body response I get from the wiql query:

To update the work item if exists, I need to work item ID.
To get that I used :
          @{body('Check_if_work_item_exists')['workItems'][0]['id']}

It returns "5648\n"
and here's the parameters it sending to update the work item ID:
            {
                "account": "MyOrgName",
                     "id": "5648\n",
                "project": "MyProjName",
         "workItem/title": "test test test 88",
   "workItem/description": "<p>It's a test for devops integration 88</p>",
                   "type": "User Story"
            }
               

The error I am getting:
             <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 
             4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
             <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
             <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"> 
             </HEAD>
             <BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
             <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
             </BODY></HTML>


Test the step to update a work item and it works fine:

The only difference is the ID. According to the error message, the request URL is invalid. It should be caused by the work item id "5648\n".
Can not see your workflow settings, however you need to find a way to retrieve the correct work item id. In your scenario, it should be "5648" but not "5648\n".

How did you capture the work item ID? Did you use the exact expression as myself?

Oh I see, you’re manually putting in 3180, the whole question is how to capture the work item ID correctly from Json body response

@Ariox66 I captured the ID from previous step, but it's a different flow with yours, since I didn't know how you set the flow (settings, expressions, etc ), so I can only point out the problem and give your suggestion. Anyway, glad to know that you solved the issue with the workaround you shared. It should be a good solution in your   flow. You can mark it as a answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

As a workaround I added an Initialize a variable before condition to set the work Item ID if exist :
This works fine, but will leave this question open in case someone came up with a better answer.
If(empty(body('Check_if_work_item_exists')['workItems']),1,body('Check_if_work_item_exists')['workItems'][0]['id'])


